# How can I instantiate a module every n clock cycles?

Tags: verilog

I am fairly new to Verilog, and I am editing an open source Verilog code for shake256 which instantiates two modules `padder` and `f_permutation`.

Here is the top module:

```
`define low_pos(w,b)      ((w)*64 + (b)*8)
`define low_pos2(w,b)     `low_pos(w,7-b)
`define high_pos(w,b)     (`low_pos(w,b) + 7)
`define high_pos2(w,b)    (`low_pos2(w,b) + 7)

module keccak(clk, reset, in, in_ready, is_last, byte_num, buffer_full, out, out_ready);
    input              clk, reset;
    input      [63:0]  in;
    input              in_ready, is_last;
    input      [2:0]   byte_num;
    output             buffer_full; /* to "user" module */
    output     [511:0] out;
    output reg         out_ready;

    reg                state;     /* state == 0: user will send more input data
                                   * state == 1: user will not send any data */
    wire       [1087:0] padder_out,
                       padder_out_1; /* before reorder byte */
    //wire       [575:0] padder_out,
    //                   padder_out_1; /* before reorder byte */                       
    wire               padder_out_ready;
    wire               f_ack;
    wire      [1599:0] f_out;
    wire               f_out_ready;
    wire       [511:0] out1;      /* before reorder byte */
    reg        [10:0]  i;         /* gen "out_ready" */
    genvar w, b;

    assign out1 = f_out[1599:1599-511];

    always @ (posedge clk)
      if (reset)
        i <= 0;
      else
        i <= {i[9:0], state & f_ack};

    always @ (posedge clk)
      if (reset)
        state <= 0;
      else if (is_last)
        state <= 1;

    /* reorder byte ~ ~ */
    generate
      for(w=0; w<8; w=w+1)
        begin : L0
          for(b=0; b<8; b=b+1)
            begin : L1
              assign out[`high_pos(w,b):`low_pos(w,b)] = out1[`high_pos2(w,b):`low_pos2(w,b)];
            end
        end
    endgenerate

    generate
      //for(w=0; w<9; w=w+1)
      for(w=0; w<17; w=w+1)
        begin : L2
          for(b=0; b<8; b=b+1)
            begin : L3
              assign padder_out[`high_pos(w,b):`low_pos(w,b)] = padder_out_1[`high_pos2(w,b):`low_pos2(w,b)];
            end
        end
    endgenerate

    always @ (posedge clk)
      if (reset)
        out_ready <= 0;
      else if (i[10])
        out_ready <= 1;

    padder
      padder_ (clk, reset, in, in_ready, is_last, byte_num, buffer_full, padder_out_1, padder_out_ready, f_ack);

    f_permutation
      f_permutation_ (clk, reset, padder_out, padder_out_ready, f_ack, f_out, f_out_ready);
endmodule

`undef low_pos
`undef low_pos2
`undef high_pos
`undef high_pos2
```

The `padder_` module takes 17 cycles, and the `f_permutation_` module takes 12 cycles. I want to run these two modules continuously. I want to instantiate the `padder` module every 17 cycle so that I can save time and pad the input in advance for the next hash input. Is it possible? How can I instantiate the `padder` module every 17 cycle? Is there an easy way to do it?

I tried using a counter and an `if` statement inside an `always` block, but I was not able to instantiate a module under an `always` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can not **instantiate** a module at a specific time, but you can **enable** a module at a specific time (and disable it at another time).

Typically, you would use a module input port to control when the module is enabled or disabled.  You can enable the module for 17 cycles (or however many cycles you require).

You know that Verilog describes hardware.  Think of Verilog modules as components on a printed circuit board.  Once you build the board, the components are always there.  They don't appear at certain times after you power up the board.

When you write Verilog code, the module instances are created during compilation and elaboration.  The instances are there at simulation time 0, and they all remain for the duration of the simulation.

You should not instantiate a module in an `always` block.